# Erlang syntax error before: 'end' in line 55

Tags: erlang, syntax-error

Cant find the syntax error, i searched for misplaced/missing  ";" , "," , "end" and also searched for missing parentheses but no luck.
Any ideas?

PD: Sorry for bad English and Spanglish code

```
partida(ID,Tablero,Turno,Name1,Psocket1,Name2,Psocket2,SpectList) ->
 case (Psocket1 == " ") of
 true -> F = fun() -> case mnesia:read(juegos,ID) of
        [P1] ->
            case mnesia:read(nombre,P1#juegos.jg1) of
                [] -> exit(normal);
                [A] -> P2 = A#nombre.psocket
            end,
            case mnesia:read(nombre,P1#juegos.jg2) of
                [] -> exit(normal);
                [B] -> P3 = B#nombre.psocket
            end,
            Res = {P1#juegos.jg1,P2,P1#juegos.jg2,P3,P1#juegos.spect};
         _  -> Res = ok,exit(normal)                         
        end,
        Res end,
        {atomic,Arg} = mnesia:transaction(F),
        partida(ID,Tablero,Turno,element(1,Arg),element(2,Arg),element(3,Arg),element(4,Arg),element(5,Arg))
end,
receive
    case Jugada of
        [Pj,"bye"] -> ok;
        [Pj,F]   -> Posicion = element(1,string:to_integer(F)),
                    case (Name1 == Pj) and ((Turno rem 2) == 1) of
                        true -> case not(Posicion == error) and  (Posicion < 10) of
                                    true -> ok;%%jugada valida
                                    _  -> ok %%Jugada ilegal
                                end;
                        false ->ok %%No es tu turno
                    end,
                    case (Name2 == Pj) and ((Turno rem 2) == 0) of
                        true -> case (not(Posicion == error) and (Posicion < 10)) of
                                    true ->ok; %%jugada valida
                                     _ -> ok %%Jugada ilegal
                                end;
                        false -> ok %%No es tu turno
                    end
    end
end, %% Line 55
ASD = get_spects(ID),partida(ID,Tablero,Turno,Name1,Psocket1,Name2,Psocket2,ASD).
```

Comment: Seems like something wrong with receive syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in `receive` clause.

```
1> case oops of _ -> ok end. % correct
ok
2> receive (case oops of _ -> ok end) end.
* 1: syntax error before: 'end'
```

`receive` statement is used for reading Erlang messages of the process. Here you are not waiting for any message and you are doing something in body of `receive` clause! If you don't want to check the message but you want to do something after receiving first message, I recommend to use `_` for pattern matching:

```
3> receive _ -> (case oops of _ -> ok end) end.
%% Waits for a message
```

Actually you can have no `receive` clause, but like this:

```
4> receive after 1000 -> done end. %% Sleeps 1000 ms and does not care about any incoming message
done
```

But you can't write code in `receive` clause without any pattern matching.